# My append does not seem to work although I console logged it and no error was shown (newbie question)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing with functions and creating the input fields etc. more dynamically, but for some reason I cannot append my input field to my field.
I used `console.log()`and no error was really shown. I am wondering what I am doing wrong and how to prevent these newbie mistakes a bit easier.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="save.php" method="POST" id="testing">

            </form>
            <h1>test aswell</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript/ jquery:

```
function getEblock() {
    let eBlock = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-2'
    }));
    return eBlock;
}

$(getEblock()).appendTo('#testing');
$(getEblock()).append(getInputDistanceTime());

function getInputDistanceTime() {
    let inputField = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'distanceTime',
        'placeholder': 'test',
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return inputField;
}
```

How the header looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

I did declare everything in my header.

Comment: I may assume :  $(getEblock().append(getInputDistanceTime())).appendTo('#testing');  append to newly created element.....

Comment: clarify please?

Comment: this happens because when you append the getInputDistanceTime() you re calling again getEblock() which returns a new div, and that div is not appended to the dom, but the previous one, which is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getEblock function returns a div while getInputDistanceTime returns an input.

I assume you need to append the newly created input to the newly created div and this one to the  testing form.

In order to achieve this you need to change your code:

```
$(getEblock().append(getInputDistanceTime())).appendTo('#testing');
```

Steps:

1. create the div: getEblock()
2. append to this the input field: getInputDistanceTime()
3. append the div created at step 1 to the form: .appendTo('#testing')

```js
function getEblock() {
    let eBlock = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-2'
    }));
    return eBlock;
}
function getInputDistanceTime() {
    let inputField = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'distanceTime',
        'placeholder': 'test',
        'class': 'form form-control'
    }));
    return inputField;
}

$(function () {
  $(getEblock().append(getInputDistanceTime())).appendTo('#testing');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="save.php" method="POST" id="testing">
            </form>
            <h1>test aswell</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So my code didnt work because I was calling it to early?

Comment: Oke, but now comes the second question: Why isn't the code that (obviously) works in your snipet not in my code? Is it maybe because I am using 3.1 instead of 2.1? (the jquery library)

Comment: it worked! Oke, so to wrap it up: where it all appends should be in a function (document).ready, and the append should've been at the bottom of the functions. Correct?

Comment: no. If you wrap in dom ready you do not need to add your js at the bottom. Instead, your functions may be global, so they can be defined outside the dom ready. I hope this will help you.